# Странно обновляется ListView

Tags: android, c#, listview, xamarin

Пытаюсь реализовать удаление элементов списка по нажатию кнопки в этом же элементе. По факту в массиве удаляется нужный элемент, но выполнение команды NotifyDataSetChanged(); которая, по идее, обновляет список, удаляется последний элемент списка независимо от удаленного элемента. Почему так? Кто-нибудь сталкивался?

```
 public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
 {
      var item = items[position];
      View view = convertView;
      Button btnDelete;

      if (view == null)
      {
           view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.item_view, null);
           view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1).Text = item.title;        

           btnDelete = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button2);

           btnDelete.Click += (sender, args) =>
           {
               items.RemoveAt(position);                   
               NotifyDataSetChanged();
           };
       }           
       return view;
   }
```

Comment: Вы назначаете обработчик один раз, при создании view. position при этом зафиксировался. Кстати текст вы устанавливаете тоже только при создании... Самое простое - вынесите все кроме Inflate из условия. Из advanced почитайте про viewholder.

Comment: Ну вообще он удаляет элемент из ListView не зависимо от полученой позиции. Оставил только  Inflate в скобках (еще раз), но так вообще начинается неведомая хрень. Например список из 6 элементов. Кликаю по 5 му - всё правильно, удаляется 5-й. Кликаю по 4-му - удаляется 4-й и 6-й, хотя в массиве переданном в  адаптер все нормально удаляется. Попытка третий раз кликнуть приводит к двойному срабатыванию события - удаляется 2 элемента из массива с вылетом position за его пределы и соответственно "эксцепт рейнндж". Большей хрени чем с этими адаптерами я в жизни не встречал ))) Вроде все по примеру ((

Comment: Эм... Это такая особенность c#, что делагаты накапливаются, а не заменяются. Из вариантов: 1) удалять обработчик сначала (либо создать именованный, либо через рефлексию), потом устанавливать новый. 2) Записывать куда-нибудь позицию (например в tag кнопки удаления), при удалении брать позицию из tag'а. 3) Реализовать ViewHolder, в котором хранить текущую позицию, удалять по ней. ЗЫ С шарпом не работаю, но поглядел пару форумов, там какой-то ад творится: костыль на костыле...

Comment: @YuraIvanov: На это, кстати, намекает `+=`.

Comment: @VladD это понятно, просто в xamarin решили, что setListener и addListener это по сути одно и то же и не стали заморачиваться, ну типа кто вешает клики на элементы несколько раз... В итоге одни и те же снипеты с точностью до синтаксиса для java и c# приводят к разному поведению. Xamarin сообщество только в начале пути...

Answer (score 0):

посмотрите лучше в сторону [RecyclerView](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/recyclerview/). по сути это тот же `listview` но более оптимизирован. + заставляет реализовывать `viewholder` что уже избавляет от ряда проблем. 
зы [recyclerview clickevent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35725324/recyclerview-click-event)

Answer (score 0):

@Yura Ivanov спасибо. Разобрался как добавлять теги и нашел пример с удалением и  добавление события. Вот этот код начал нормально удалять.

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            var item = items[position];
            View view = convertView;
            Button btnDelete;

            if (view == null)
            {
                view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.item_view, null);
            }  
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1).Text = item.title;        

            btnDelete = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button2);

            btnDelete.SetTag(Resource.Id.button2, position);

            btnDelete.Click -= MyClickEvent;
            btnDelete.Click += MyClickEvent;

            return view;
        }

        void MyClickEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int i = (int)((Button)sender).GetTag(Resource.Id.button2);
            items.RemoveAt(i);
            NotifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```